# Sorting a hash from the first key to the last (Perl)

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have the following hash, and I wish to keep it in the order I've set it in; is this even possible? If not, do any alternatives exist?

```
my %hash = ('Key1' => 'Value1', 'Key2' => 'Value2', 'Key3' => 'Value3');
```

Do I need to write a custom sorting subroutine? What are my options?

Thank you!

Comment: No, an array doesn't preserve insertion order either. `$a[1]="a"; $a[0]="b"; print "@a\n";` prints `b a`. Both array and hashes return elements in the order they are physically found.

Comment: for what reason you need to sort associative array(hash)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash

```
use Tie::IxHash;
my %hash;
tie %hash,'Tie::IxHash';
```

This hash will maintain its order.

Comment: I was hoping for something that wouldn't require an external library, however, this should do the trick anyway.
Tested and working, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aUndexed). Quoting its Synopsis:

```
use Tie::Hash::Indexed;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::Hash::Indexed';

%hash = ( I => 1, n => 2, d => 3, e => 4 );
$hash{x} = 5;

print keys %hash, "\n";    # prints 'Index'
print values %hash, "\n";  # prints '12345'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
print "$_=$hash{$_}\n" for sort keys %hash;
```

if you want it sorted in alphabetic order.

If you need to retain original order, see other posts.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to do the same as you sometimes do with arrays: specify the keys.

```
 for (0..$#a) {  # Sorted array keys
     say $a[$_];
 }

 for (sort keys %h) {  # Sorted hash keys
     say $h{$_};
 }

 for (0, 1, 3) {  # Sorted array keys
     say $h{$_};
 }

 for (qw( Key1 Key2 Key3 )) {  # Sorted hash keys
     say $h{$_};
 }
```

You can also fetch the ordered values as follows:

```
 my @values = @h{qw( Key1 Key2 Key3 )};
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you're going to access the data. If you just want to store them and access the last/first values, you can always put hashes in an array and use push() and pop().

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10;

use Data::Dumper;

my @hashes;

foreach( 1..5 ){
    push @hashes, { "key $_" => "foo" };
}


say Dumper(\@hashes);
```